# minify es2017 with gulp

Tags: javascript, gulp, minify, gulp-uglify

Hey guys I'm currently using uglify-gulp with babel to minify my js. And it works great with es2015 and es2016. But it breaks if I try to do es2017.

Does anyone know any workarounds to minify js that is using the new experimental features in es2017?

```
gulp.src('build/js/bundled/bundle.js')
.pipe(babel({
    compact: false,
    presets: ["es2017", "react"], 
    plugins: ["transform-decorators-legacy"],
}))
.pipe(uglify())
.pipe(gulp.dest('build/js/bundled'));
```

which generates this error

```
GulpUglifyError: unable to minify JavaScript
```

If I change es2017 to es2015/es2016 it will minify my bundles that don't have es2017 features just fine. But I want to be able to use those experimental features and be able to minify my code

Comment: Uhhh What is the "break"? What is the code?

Comment: see edit. Basically if i have es2017, gulp-uglify breaks with the error

"GulpUglifyError: unable to minify JavaScript". But if I change it to es2015 or es2016 it works on code that don't have es2017 features, but I want to use those new features

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that Uglify can't parse some ES2015 features, so you need to transpile those down to ES5 (`es2017` targets Node 5+).

With [these webpack instructions](https://github.com/bettiolo/babel-preset-es2017#webpack), specifically the presets and plugins, you should be able to get it working (at least it did for me, as I could replicate similar Uglify issues by just using `es2017`):

```
presets: ['es2015', 'es2017', 'react'],
plugins: ['transform-runtime', 'transform-decorators-legacy', 'transform-class-properties']
```

Comment: Worked like a charm thank you! It should be noted i had to add

`compact: true` to the options or i'd get an "The code generator has deoptimised the styling of.." warning