# Javascript minifier supporting ES2017 async/await feature

Tags: javascript, node.js, minify, uglifyjs, ecmascript-2017

Currently appears as UglifyJS2 and Google Closure doesn't support JavaScript minification of scripts including async/await usage without transpiling them.

Is there a way or another minifier to get these JavaScript scripts minified without the need to transpile them?

Comment: Just curious, why would you need to minify them if you can't use them in production anyway?

Comment: Because it's not true I can't use it in production. All main browsers support this specification ( http://caniuse.com/#search=await). Only Microsoft Edge on mobile devices will support this feature without the flag in the next version. Also NodeJS supports it. So for my requirements it's perfectly production ready.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

UglifyJS introduced support for async/await in uglify-es@3.0.17
( https://github.com/mishoo/UglifyJS2/issues/1789)

Answer (score -1):

Not yet. Right now in order to minify the code you will need to transpile it first.

There is an open issue in UglifyJS2 repo - Harmony support #448:

- https://github.com/mishoo/UglifyJS2/issues/448

You can track the progress of this issue. Hopefully the support will get added.

If you are willing to add the transpilation step then see this answer:

- [minify es2017 with gulp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38879629/minify-es2017-with-gulp)

Comment: Unfortunatelly I don't want transpile the code, I just want code to be minified. :(